# Regex not working correctly all the time, why?

Tags: regex

Regex just working in some cases, other not working.

https://regex101.com/r/p5u3N6/1

I expected regex match only groups of two "{ } { }" without nothing between { }

Comment: *match only groups of two "{ } { }" without nothing between { }*. I'm not sure I understand what this means. In either case, your regex has stuff between. You have a space `\s` between `{...}` and `{...}`. Is that what you mean by "nothing"? But you said "without nothing" so you want something? Please: (1) put the regex in your question, not just in a link, (2) provide examples of what you want to match and perhaps a couple of things you don't want to match if it adds clarity.

Comment: Your regex also includes an `m` option which makes it multi-line, thus the "ERROR" you are pointing out.  A `\s` matches a "white space" character, which includes a new line, a tab, and a few others.

Comment: In the part with the error, the first `.*` is matching all the way through to the next group. `.` matches all of those characters, so why not? You could try using a negated character group to prevent it from matching curly brackets `[^}]`. Play around with capture groups on regex101 to get a better idea of what each part of your pattern is matching: https://regex101.com/r/p5u3N6/2

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that we wish to only capture, three of our inputs listed in the demo using an expression similar to:

```
(\{.*?\}(.+?){.*?\})
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/o0cyI6/1)

or

```
(\{(.+?)\}(.+?){(.+?)\})
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/pQmili/1)

Answer (score 0):

The `.*?` in the first part of your pattern is passing through the unexpected parts of your input until it finds because `.` accepts all of those characters. Simply making the quantifier lazy with `?` isn't enough-- it will still proceed until it finds a match.

`\{[^}]*?\}\s\{[^}]*?\}`

https://regex101.com/r/p5u3N6/5

Comment: @GleidsonHenrique Glad to hear it works! Can you please mark my answer as the accepted solution for your question?

Comment: I had no privileges to score, but now I have. Thank you again.

Comment: @GleidsonHenrique Oh, it's not the score. There should be a check mark graphic underneath the score that only the person who asked the question can see.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your requirements, I suppose you only want pairs of `{}{}` to match, and allow nothing more than one space between these two. You can try this `\{([^\{]+)\}\ \{([^\}]+)\}`.